# render_template unable to jsonify object

Tags: python, flask

I'm not doing a lot of web development, so my knowledge in this field is pretty basic. However I have to write a simple web application using **python** an **flask**.

In this application I have a simple class that looks like this:

```
class Task(object):       
    def __init__(self, id, title):
       super(Task, self).__init__()
       self.id = id
       self.title = title
```

It can be assumed that `id` is an `integer` and `title` is a `(unicode) string`.

In a view function I want to render a template passing a `list` of `Task objects`, like this:

```
@app.route('/tasklist')
@login_required
def tasklist():
    tasklist = [
       Task(1, u"Task 1"), 
       Task(2, u"Task 2"),
       Task(3, u"Task 3"),
       Task(4, u"Task 4")
    ]
    return render_template( "tasklist.html", tasklist=tasklist)
```

When the view function is called, I get the following **error** message:

```
TypeError: <models.Task object at 0x103861210> is not JSON serializable
```

When I look around on the interwebs I see many examples, where they pass lists of objects to views using `render_template`. So I wonder what am I missing? My object only uses basic datatypes. Do I have to overload a specific function?

Calling `render_template` with a list of simple strings (instead of class instances) works fine.

I know, this is a very basic question, but I didn't find a satisfying answer for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about flask but it seems it needs JSON serializable objects so here's what I think.

Generally objects are not JSON serializable. You have to convert it to JSON serializable object like for example a dictionary:

```
class Task(object):       
    def __init__(self, id, title):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "title": self.title
        }
```

and then

```
tasklist = [
   Task(1, u"Task 1"), 
   Task(2, u"Task 2"),
   Task(3, u"Task 3"),
   Task(4, u"Task 4")
]
tasklist = [task.as_dict() for task in tasklist]
return render_template( "tasklist.html", tasklist=tasklist)
```

Comment: Too easy! Thank you very much. I thought that the conversion is done implicitly because I saw it in so many examples (but maybe this was done by another module). However, this solution works just fine for me!